# JavaScript: pulse button that disappears when scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a web site that has got a pulsing button (#scrollarrow) at the bottom of the page.
When I start to scroll the page, this button disappears.
I obtain this effect with the following jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(window).scroll(function(){              
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
            $('#scrollarrow').fadeOut('slow');
        }else{
            $('#scrollarrow').fadeIn('slow');
        } 
    }); 
});
```

Until there, no problem.
The issues come when I try to add the pulse effect (a simple change of opacity):

```
function pulse(){
    $('#scrollarrow').delay(200).fadeOut('slow').delay(50).fadeIn('slow',pulse);
}
```

I really can't apply this function to the code above. The max result I get is to see the button pulsing after the scrolling, that's it, in effect, the reverse of my goal.
I tryed a lot of different combinations but none of these seems to work properly.

Any suggestions, please?

Comment: Can you please post a jsfiddle for us to see what you mean ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have the arrow pulsing when the user hasn't started scrolling you could do it like this: **http://jsfiddle.net/P99Ey/28/**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // This function will animate the button and then 
    //call it self on completing the animation
    function pulse() {
        // This will make sure the button only animates 
        // when the user is at the top of the page
        if ($(window).scrollTop() <= 50) {
            $('#scrollarrow').delay(200).fadeOut('slow').delay(50).fadeIn('slow', pulse);
        }
    }
    // This will trigger the animation on when document is ready
    pulse();

    $(window).scroll(function(){              
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
            // This will stop the animation
            $('#scrollarrow').clearQueue();
            // This will hide the bar
            $('#scrollarrow').fadeOut("slow");
        }else{
            // This will restart the animation when the user 
            // scrolls back to the top of the page
            pulse();
        } 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Hi Mathias, thanks but I your script seems not to work.
Unfortunately the button remains always visible (pulsing) after scrolling, but doesn't disappears.

Comment: I think I fixed it now. Changed $(this) to $(window)

Comment: Thanks Mathias, it is working..one time only! :( If I scroll back up to the top of the page, the button appears again (right) but losing it's pulsing effect (wrong). :(
Sorry but i try to understand why, without get the answer.

Comment: @user3323340 Well, if you want the pulsing again you need to call `pulse()` again in the scroll eventhandler. See my update

Comment: Thanks Mathias, the script works perfectly on chrome and ie, but in safari it doesn'tworks. Using safary, the button doesn't disappears if i scroll down the menu. 
but into a sample jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/P99Ey/30/), it's works perfectly on safari too. So, at least, I have to understand what is the elementthat bother the script...maybe the css...argh!
However Thanks so much!!!

Comment: yeah man!!! Now it is working perfectly!!! Thanks!!!
The mistery remains. Why the script worked on the jsfiddle sample using safari and the same script, always into safari, doesn't goes right on my website?
Anyway, now it is perfect!!! I really thaks you! :)

Comment: Your welcome! Please also accept my answer :) That is how you let people now the question is solved :)

Answer (score 0):

Might be worth looking into [CSS3 Animations](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp), you can set a couple of keyframes to pulse the button and keep it separate from the JavaScript. Whilst the [browser support](http://caniuse.com/css-animation) isn't as good using CSS3, there are performance benefits to letting the browser figure out the animation. And it obviously will work for those with JavaScript disabled.

Comment: In fact Charlie, for now, I am using a combination of css and jsquery but I would prefer to do all the work with a js script

Answer (score 0):

I guess this will help you out :

**HTML**

```
<div id="scrollarrow">Test</div>
```

**css**

```
#scrollarrow
{
    position:fixed;
}
```

**jquery**

```
$(function () {
    function run_animation($element, delay, duration) {
        $element.delay(delay).fadeToggle(duration, function () {
            run_animation($element, delay, duration);
        });
    }
    run_animation($('#scrollarrow'), 100, 50);
});

 $(window).scroll(function(){              
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
            $('#scrollarrow').fadeOut('slow');
        }else{
            $('#scrollarrow').fadeIn('slow');
            // This will restart the animation when the user 
            // scrolls back to the top of the page
            pulse();
        } 
    });
```

**Demo** : [click me :)](http://jsfiddle.net/mahmoudSarhan/P99Ey/31/)

Comment: mahmoud nezar sarhan dor thetime u spent forme,but i have just solvedmy problemwith thescript of mathias! :) Hope don't bother u this thing! :)

Comment: hhhhhhhhhhh no problem brother 

, 
I tried to help :)